# How to build UDT Array for C# to Call Oracle Stored Proc

Tags: c#, oracle

```
        public static XXCMI.PWR_FWD_PRICES_TABLE TestCreateUDT1()
        {
            // BizTalk XML Looks like this 
            /*
<ns0:CHN_POWER_FWD_PRICES_SP xmlns:ns0="http://Microsoft.LobServices.OracleDB/2007/03/XXCMI/Procedure" xmlns:ns3="http://Microsoft.LobServices.OracleDB/2007/03/XXCMI/UserType">
    <ns0:P_PWR_TAB>
        <ns3:PWR_FWD_PRICES_REC_TYPE>
            <ns3:OPR_DATE>2023-06-12</ns3:OPR_DATE>
            <ns3:MONTH>2023-06-01</ns3:MONTH>
            <ns3:HUBCDTPEAK>56.48</ns3:HUBCDTPEAK>
            <ns3:HUBCDTOFFPEAK>22.77</ns3:HUBCDTOFFPEAK>
            <ns3:HUBCDTWKNDPEAK>58.39</ns3:HUBCDTWKNDPEAK>
            <ns3:CDTPEAK>59.23</ns3:CDTPEAK>
            <ns3:CDTOFFPEAK>24.27</ns3:CDTOFFPEAK>
            <ns3:CDTWKNDPEAK>60.87</ns3:CDTWKNDPEAK>
        </ns3:PWR_FWD_PRICES_REC_TYPE>
        <ns3:PWR_FWD_PRICES_REC_TYPE>             
             */
            var objTable = new XXCMI.PWR_FWD_PRICES_TABLE();
            var objrow = new XXCMI.PWR_FWD_PRICES_REC_TYPE();
            // changed date to avoid conflict 
            objrow.OPR_DATE = System.Convert.ToDateTime("2023-01-12");
            objrow.MONTH = System.Convert.ToDateTime("2023-01-01"); 
            objrow.HUBCDTPEAK=56.48M;
            objrow.HUBCDTOFFPEAK = 22.77M;
            objrow.HUBCDTWKNDPEAK = 58.39M;
            objrow.CDTPEAK = 59.23M;
            objrow.CDTOFFPEAK = 24.27M;
            objrow.CDTWKNDPEAK = 60.87M; 

            //objTable = { objrow };
            objTable.Array = { objrow };


            return objTable; 
        }
```

The line "objTable.Array = { objrow };" has an error.  How do I create an array with just (or maybe two) rows in it?

Other things I have tried:

```
    //var objTableFactory = new XXCMI.PWR_FWD_PRICES_REC_TYPEFactory(); 
    //objTableFactory.CreateObject(objTable)

    //objTable = { objRow };
    //objTable.Array = new { objRow };
    objRows[] obj = { objRow };
    objTable.Array = objRows;
```

I just got a clean build with this, about to test more:

```
    XXCMI.PWR_FWD_PRICES_REC_TYPE[] objRows = { objRow };
    objTable.Array = objRows;
```

I have referenced a C# .DLL that was generated by BizTalk.
We were having an issue with BizTalk 2020 and wanted to try to reproduce to get more info in C#.
Here is the object browser for that .DLL:

[image]

In a separate routine, I want to try to call the Stored Proc.
I'm setting this:

```
 p.UdtTypeName = "XXCMI.PWR_FWD_PRICES_REC_TYPE";
```

Answer (score 0):

With a colleague's help, we got this working by using a List and the ToArray method.

```
    var objTable = new XXCMI.PWR_FWD_PRICES_TABLE();

    List<XXCMI.PWR_FWD_PRICES_REC_TYPE> objArray = new List<XXCMI.PWR_FWD_PRICES_REC_TYPE>();

    var objRow = new XXCMI.PWR_FWD_PRICES_REC_TYPE();
    objRow.OPR_DATE = System.Convert.ToDateTime("2023-01-12");
    objRow.MONTH = System.Convert.ToDateTime("2023-01-01"); 
    objRow.HUBCDTPEAK = 56.48M;
    objRow.HUBCDTOFFPEAK = 22.77M;
    objRow.HUBCDTWKNDPEAK = 58.39M;
    objRow.CDTPEAK = 59.23M;
    objRow.CDTOFFPEAK = 24.27M;
    objRow.CDTWKNDPEAK = 60.87M;

    objArray.Add(objRow); 

    objTable.Array = objArray.ToArray();
```